# Why is the json returned by the Advanced REST Client different than that returned by the Requests module in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

ARC:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

I saved the returned json in a .json file and transformed it into a pandas dataframe using:

```
temp_json = pd.read_json('TempJson.json', orient='columns')
```

This works great.
But then I used the requests module in Python 2.7.13, specifically:

```
myResponse = requests.post(url, json= payload, headers = headers)
jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)
```

And 1) the json structure is much different than temp_json and 2) it completely wrecks my code. Any idea why?

Snippet from temp_json:

```
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
 "maxResults": 250,
  "total": 3,
  "issues": [
{
  "expand": "operations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
  "id": "1954523",
  "key": "SPGC-14075",
  "fields": {"summary": "QA: Build concentration support into CDC automation",
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "https://itec-jira.fmr.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/20",
      "id": "20",
      "description": "Default sub-task",
      "iconUrl": "https://itec-
 jira.fmr.com/images/icons/issuetypes/subtask_alternate.png",
      "name": "Sub task",
      "subtask": true
```

Sample from python json:

```
{
  "issues": [
{
  "key": "SPGC-25646",
  "fields": {
    "status": {
      "statusCategory": {
        "name": "To Do",
        "self": "https://itec-jira.fmr.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
        "id": 2,
        "key": "new",
        "colorName": "blue-gray"
      },.....
```

Comment: Show the two different json you get please.

Comment: I posted snippets.

Comment: @jenkelblankel: Your snippets don't show any differences; the dictionaries could very well be equal but just have their keys listed in a different order.

Comment: Yeah you and @Dan below both pointed that out. When I said differences that's what I meant. The data is def the same just the order. But I didn't know json loads srambled so makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` will create a python dict which is hashed so the contents will be in scrambled order. Check that json.loads returns the same dict for both the request and the tempfile. If they are different then the data is different. You can use the pretty print library to help you debug deep nested json.